# is there a shell / bash way to alias... find . -type f -exec grep -l <some word here> {} \;;

Tags: bash, shell

basically, this command does a recursive grep through all files in all sub-directories and I use it ALOT

but it's looooong and takes awhile to type

so I was wondering if instead of...

```bsh
$ find . -type f -exec grep -l <some word here> {} \;;
```

that there was a way to alias it or something in my .bashrc so that I could just do something like...

```bsh
$ findrecursive <some word here>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  In bash:

```bsh
function findrecursive() { find . -type f -exec grep -l "$1" {} \;; }
```

And then call it like this:

```bsh
findrecursive "hello"
```

Comment: didn't know you could just declare a function...  thought you had to do something with `alias findrecursive='...'`   (im bash noob)

Comment: Just to add, if you use "-Hn" instead of "-l" for the grep options, you'll also get the line number and the line outputted.

Answer (score 7):

I just assume you use Linux and GNU tools, I don't know if it's a GNU extension, but otherwise the snippet below should do what you want, quick and easy:

```
grep -r <search-regexp>
```

The above doesn't follow symlinks, if you want your search to do that you need:

```
grep -R <search-regexp>
```

In some distros there is an `rgrep` command which I just think is an alias to `grep -r`. If you don't have it just do `alias rgrep="grep -r"` and put it in your .bashrc or equivalent.

Comment: For example: `grep -r <some word here> .`

Comment: Works splendidly in this case; but for a more general answer, consider bash's `function`.  (Example in my answer below.)  Cheers.

Comment: @ron.rothman This has nothing to do with bash `function`. He wants to grep recursively through files, so then creating a bash script and execute find who then forks grep is just an unecessarily complex way of doing it.

Comment: oooo thanks, i forgot about that grep -r option (i guess i became permanently accustomed to using the long `find` one at some point)

Comment: @DavidLam You can use `find` and then fork `grep` with exec, however it's unnecessary complex and probably less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make it into a shell script and put it into one of your bins. For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# findrecursive.sh

find . -type f -exec grep -l "$1" {} \;;
```

Then, after you have made it executable (e.g. `chmod` and put in a path directory somewhere (e.g. `/bin`) you can call it by saying:

```bsh
findrecursive.sh <some word here>
```

Of course you don't need the `.sh` extension, it's only a convention for sorting. And you may want to note that the $1 will become `<some word here>` when you call the script.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, these solutions didn't work for me in LUbuntu using bash in LXTerminal. I added the following to my `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
function find_helper() { /usr/bin/find . -iname "$@" -readable -prune -print; }
alias find='find_helper'
```

And I now have the behavior I expected. For example:

```
find *.xml
```

Searches recursively from `pwd` filtering out the `Permission Denied` messages.